# Basic Linker Script

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm trying to clean up the commandline required to build my program. Right now, the command in my makefile looks like this.

gcc -o myapp myapp.c liba.a -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet -lPocoUtil -lstdc++

And I have other shared libraries to add to it!

I believe a linker script would clean things up nicely. However, all the examples I've seen of linker scripts talk about memory management, requiring values which I do not know how to set.

If you would write a very basic linker script that included the libraries noted above, I would be most grateful!

Thank you so much in advance for your time.

Comment: Maybe you're rather looking for makefiles?

Comment: You definitely don't want a linker script. A linker script is for when you need to control the layout of your final binary file - which you don't need to do. You may consider splitting your command line into compile and link stages, which will simplify it slightly, but it won't ever be totally clean (witness the crazy long command lines generated by many open-source project makefiles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Makefile:

```
LDLIBS = -la -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet -lPocoUtil -lstd++
LDFLAGS = -L.

all: myapp
```

And then just run make.

Answer (score 2):

To echo what [nneonneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204143/nneonneo) said in a comment:

A linker script will not do what you want here. Linker scripts are used to configure how the linker generates output, e.g. where different types of code and data are located in memory. There is almost never any reason to write or customize a linker script outside of embedded/low-level software development.

What you want is a Makefile, as explained by jforberg.